# Eval for array with some conditional

Tags: asp.net

How can i use Eval for array in ASP.NET WebPAge?

I want write something like `<%# Eval(Images.First().SmallImageUrl) %>` or

```
<%# Eval(Images.SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsMainIMage).SmallImageUrl) %>
```

Here is code example:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="GoodsRepeater" runat="server">

              <HeaderTemplate>
              </HeaderTemplate>

              <ItemTemplate>

               <div class="<%# (Container.ItemIndex % 2)!=0 ? "GoodItemTdEven" : "GoodItemTdOdd" %>">   

                 <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# "/" + Eval("GoodsImages.First().SmallImageUrl") %>' AlternateText='<%# Eval("Name") %>'  runat="server" />

                 <div class="GoodItemDescriptionDiv" >

                   <asp:HyperLink CssClass="GoodItemNameText"  NavigateUrl='<%# "~/Pages/Main/Catalog.aspx?productId=" +  Eval("Id") %>' Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' runat="server" />
                   <%--<span class="GoodItemNameText">  <%# Eval("Name") %> </span> <br /> <br />--%>
                   <span class="GoodItemDescriptionText" > <%# Eval("Description") %> </span> 
                   <br />

                 </div>


                </div>

              </ItemTemplate>

              <FooterTemplate>
              </FooterTemplate>

          </asp:Repeater>
```

I have an exception 'DataBinding: 'First()' is not a valid indexed expression.'

Comment: What's the problem will the code above? Do you mean the list conversion, i.e. .ToList()?

Comment: What is Images? And why is Eval necessary here? If SmallImageUrl is string, Eval should not be needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eval uses reflection (or indexing on known types such as datatable/view) - I would suggest that you use the actual expression on `Container.DataItem` - for example

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# "/" + (([your object type])Container.DataItem).GoodsImages[0].SmallImageUrl %>' AlternateText=...
```

This is assuming that you are binding the repeater to collection of `[your object type]` and that type has method named `GoodsImages` returning an array.

Note that if you wish to use extension methods such as `First` then compiler looks for them only within namespaces that you are importing. So again you need to use either [@Import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb44kack.aspx) directive or Extension class i.e. `Enumerable.First(...`)

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you create a helper method in a code-behind to get this value? It could make your markup more cleaner:

```
<%# GetImageUrl((YourImagesType)Eval("Images")) %>
```

and then in a code-behind:

```
protected static string GetImageUrl(YourImagesType images)
{
    return images
        .Where(x => x.IsMainIMage)
        .Select(x => x.SmallImageUrl)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```